# scala future timeout strange behaviour

Tags: scala, asynchronous, concurrency, future

Here is example code scala 2.13.3:

```
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext}

val scheduller: ScheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()

val promise = Promise[A]()
scheduller.schedule(
  new Runnable {
    override def run(): Unit = {
      promise.failure(new TimeoutException)
      scheduller.shutdown()
    }
  },
  500,
  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
)
Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(INF_FUTURE, promise.future))
```

the time out will work if `INF_FUTURE = Future.never` but execution will not stops if `INF_FUTURE = Future {while (true) {}}`
Can you explane what is going on here?

Comment: It worked when I tested it - which version of Scala and what ExecutionContext did you use? Was it reused single thread scheduler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you use `singleThreadScheduledExecutor`. I assume you creates `ExecutionContext` from `scheduller`:

```
val scheduller: ScheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
implicit val ec: ExecutionContextExecutor = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(scheduller)

val promise = Promise[Int]()
scheduller.schedule(
  new Runnable {
    override def run(): Unit = {
      promise.failure(new TimeoutException)
      scheduller.shutdown()
    }
  },
  500,
  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
)
```

If you create execution context only with one executor your program will evaluate synchronous and freeze inside `while (true)` loop.

If you will switch to global Execution context the problem will be missed (if your machine has more then one core):

```
implicit val ec: ExecutionContextExecutor = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global
```

in case of `Future.never` if you will wait for result like so:

```
Await.result(Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(INF_FUTURE, promise.future)).map {
  x =>
    println(x)
}, 10.seconds)
```

you will get Exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
> java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@eb88a9df
> rejected from
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@e24c7ced[Shutting
> down, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed
> tasks = 1]

which call you about problem with thread pool size.
So, you don't have any problem with `Future.never` because you didn't wait for it's result.