# Timeout exception when working with Akka Http

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, circe

I use following Scala code in my application to get auth token:

```
  def authRequest() : Future[Either[HttpError, HttpMessage]] = {
    val http = Http(actorSystem)
    val uri = Uri("https://someendpoint/oauth2/token")
    .withQuery(Query("grant_type"-> "password", "username" -> user, "password" -> password, "client_id" -> clientId))
    val request = HttpRequest(uri = uri, method = HttpMethods.POST,
      entity = HttpEntity(ContentType(MediaTypes.`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`), ""))
    logger.debug(s"Request: ${request.toString()}")
    val src = Source.single(request)
    val connFlow = http.outgoingConnection(uri.authority.host.address(), uri.effectivePort)
    val sink = Sink.head[HttpResponse]
    val result = src.via(connFlow).toMat(sink)(Keep.right).run()
    result.map{
      response => parser.decode[Token](response.entity.toString) match {
        case Right(token) => Right(token.access_token)
        case Left(_) => Left(HttpError(Unauthorized, "Authorization exception"))
      }
    }
  }
```

Then I try to get future result like this:

```
Await.result(authRequest(), Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) match {
     some logic
}
```

But I got:

```
ERROR akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl - Error during processing of request: 'Future timed out after [1 minute]'. Completing with 500 Internal Server Error response. To change default exception handling behavior, provide a custom ExceptionHandler.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Future timed out after [1 minute]
```

Even if when I execute this request with curl or postman I correctly get the token value in like 300-400 m.

FIY information, Token case class that use for parsing JSON response:

```
@JsonCodec case class Token(access_token: String, expires_in: Int, token_type: String, userId: String)
```

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64418140/scala-future-timeout-strange-behaviour. How many cores does your machine have and/or how many threads were given to the JVM/Akka?

Comment: 4 cores and according to logs Akka uses at least 14 dispatcher threads.